# in one foreach call second foreach! codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops, foreach

hier is the problem:
in codeigniter in controller I have next code:

```
$query_not_voted = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE p_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct p_id FROM p_votes where u_id = ".$this->session->userdata('u_id').") LIMIT ".$this->db->escape_str($segment_url).", ".$config['per_page'];
$q = $this->db->query($query_not_voted);
$data['myphotos'] = $q->result_array();

foreach($data['myphotos'] as $key=>$val)
{
    $query_g = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = (SELECT u_id FROM p_votes WHERE p_id = ".$val['p_id'].")";
    $q_2 = $this->db->query($query_g);
    $data['allvotess'] = $q_2->result_array();

    $query_u = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = ".$val['u_id']." LIMIT 0, 5";
    $q_1 = $this->db->query($query_u);
    $data['author'] = $q_1->result_array();
}
```

So now I have `$data['myphotos']` and this is can be outputted in view with next codes:

```
<?php foreach ($myphotos as $keys => $myphoto){ ?>
    <div id="voteblock">
    <div id="voteleft">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().$myphoto['p_small']; ?>" class="preview" title="<?php echo base_url().$myphoto['p_title']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url().$myphoto['p_thumb']; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

but how can I output `$data['allvotess']` in last foreach loop?
I tried to do same, but didn't work out.

Then I tried to push the results inside $data['myphotos'] and no good result!

So What I'm Doing???

Just need someone to help me with foreachloop insite foreachloop!!!
For a week I just can't do, I can even pay for solution right now!!!

I posted also at codeingiter forum, but they say it's easy hier is [link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/176599/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in views I use the more semantic way to write foreach and if statements, and I'll also illustrate a tiered foreach loop...

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array3 = array(1,2,3,4);

$second_array[] = $array1;
$second_array[] = $array2;
$second_array[] = $array3;
```

so now we have $second_array that is a multi-dimensional array...

```
$data->second_array = $second_array;
$this->load->view('your/view',$data);
```

in a view file...

```
<? foreach($second_array as $array): ?>  //<--start first foreach loop
    <div>do some stuff</div>
    <? foreach($array as $array_item): ?>  //<--start second foreach loop, inside the first
        <div>do some other stuff for every item in $array</div>
    <? endforeach; ?>  //<--end first foreach
<? endforeach; ?>  //<--end second foreach
```